# pd.merge. error: ValueError: Wrong number

Tags: python, pandas

In "suppliers" df I am trying to create a column called "Non-PO Category" that will have the "Category" from df "categories" based on the value in column "Unique".

Here are the dfs:

```
import pandas as pd

suppliers = pd.DataFrame({'Vendor Number': ['260508', '260525', '260549', '260561','260579','260587'],
                    'Unique': ['26050822015070', '26052522002153', '260549EXPENSE', '260561EXPENSE','2605792972508701C0000','26058738210793']})
categories = pd.DataFrame({'Vendor Number': ['260508', '260525', '260549','260587'],
                    'Unique': ['26050822015070', '26052522002153', '260549EXPENSE','26058738210793'],
                    'Category': ['Maintenance', 'IT','Facilities','Travel Agent']})
```

When I use:

```
suppliers['Non-PO Category'] = pd.merge(suppliers, categories[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
```

or

```
suppliers['Non-PO Category'] = pd.merge(suppliers, categories, how='left', left_on='Unique', right_on='Unique')
```

I get error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you use NonPO_Suppliers[['Unique','Category']]? use instead: pd.merge(final, NonPO_Suppliers, how=left, left_on=key_of_left_table, right_on=key_on_right_table)

Comment: @Trics. Thank you. I have made that change but received an error: "Wrong number of items passed 17, placement implies 1"?

Comment: @Andrian, if you can provide samples of your dataframes I'll try and get you exactly what you need.

Comment: @sophods Thank you. I have updated my question with dfs and simplified problem statement.

Comment: @Andrian Thanks for doing that. Please check the updated answer below. I think this is what you need. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting an error, is because you trying to create a new column with `pd.merge`, while by default `pd.merge` returns a **dataframe of the merged objects**. Your code:

```
suppliers['Non-PO Category'] = pd.merge(suppliers, categories[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
```

Consequently, if you alter your code and aim to return a dataframe, like this:

```
new_suppliers = pd.merge(suppliers, categories[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
```

You will get your desired output:

```
new_suppliers
Out[8]: 
  Vendor Number                 Unique      Category
0        260508         26050822015070   Maintenance
1        260525         26052522002153            IT
2        260549          260549EXPENSE    Facilities
3        260561          260561EXPENSE           NaN
4        260579  2605792972508701C0000           NaN
5        260587         26058738210793  Travel Agent
```

I hope this answers your question.

Note that this craetes a new dataframe. If you don't want this, you can overwrite your previous one by simply:

```
suppliers = pd.merge(suppliers, categories[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that this will check if values from "Unique" (df "final") are present in column "Unique" on df "NonPO_Suppliers" and not return the values in column Category (from file "NonPO_Suppliers") for corresponding values in column Unique on df "final"? I am looking to find out the category from "NonPO_Suppliers" based on column "Unique".

Comment: can you provide samples of your 2 dataframes so that I can replicate? Do it in a form of a dictionary so that I can recreate quickly please.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked with dictionary, but when I use the code to generate "Unique" column on the "suppliers" file (it is normally not there) with the code: `suppliers['Unique']=suppliers['Vendor Number'].astype(str) + supplier['Vendor Site Code'].astype(str)` - and then perform the merge as you instructed, I get "TypeError: string indices must be integers". Is it because "Unique" is alphanumeric, e.g. "260561EXPENSE", any idea how can I avoid this error? I know that this exceeds my original question. Shall I post it as a new question and mark this one as solved? Thank you!

Comment: Yes I think that's a good point. Mark this one as solved and post a new one. I will try and solve the new one too. Just let me know when you do so that I get a notification.

Comment: Can you accept and close the question please? Also, you can ask the new one.

Comment: Apologies for being late. I had to re-write my code and find away to link the files in my new question. I am accepting the answer and please see the link to my new question. Thank you very much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346930/pd-merge-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers

Comment: I think I understand the issue to your new. Please check the answer and should work :)