# pd.merge "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 files and my code is basically a series of merges that populates data from files `"lookup"` and `"NonPO"` into the file `"supplier"` and create a new df called `"final2"`. The code runs perfectly fine and produces output I am expecting until the very last merge.

The issue occurs when the very last merge is done based on the new column on `"supplier"` (vendor number + vendor site code) called `"Unique"` with a column of the same name in the file `"NonPO"`. The only thing different with this merge is that it is based on a column that was created by concatenation (previous merges used columns that were already in the files). The concatenation joins columns that may contain letters and/or numbers, e.g. `"260549" + "EXPENSE" = "260549EXPENSE"`.

The error I am getting is:

```
    runfile('//eu.ad.hertz.com/userdocs/irac920/Desktop/My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/file.py', wdir='//eu.ad.hertz.com/userdocs/irac920/Desktop/My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\\eu.ad.hertz.com\userdocs\irac920\Desktop\My Files\Python\Supplier cat testing\file.py", line 33, in <module>
    final2 = pd.merge(final2, NonPO[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My files:

1. `"supplier"` - ([File link](https://hertz-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/hz150286_hertz_net/EdGdQggMyCRHuX8L-TTO8qUB3o-D8r-IWicTsse313sq7Q?e=1WRrAA))
2. `"lookup"` - ([File link](https://hertz-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/hz150286_hertz_net/EZL-vDOEao5DpwuTiRaZqrcBUVTkRLkZp9wxZKyVm-IN2A?e=9vZ22f))
3. `"NonPO"` - ([File link](https://hertz-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/hz150286_hertz_net/Edx4XAeJnIRDp3VP36SCKlsBzawa6CYrMLHXirTpH_m0vg?e=RtKb0a))

Any help with resolving this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)


supplier = r'//eu.ad.hertz.com/userdocs/irac920/Desktop/My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/Suppliers.xlsx'
lookup = r'//eu.ad.hertz.com/userdocs/irac920/Desktop/My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/Lookup.xlsx'
NonPO = r'//eu.ad.hertz.com/userdocs/irac920/Desktop/My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/Non-PO Suppliers.xlsx'

sr = pd.read_excel(supplier)
lp_type = pd.read_excel(lookup, sheet_name=0)
lp_paygroup = pd.read_excel(lookup, sheet_name=1)
NonPO_Suppliers = pd.read_excel(NonPO)

results_type = pd.merge(sr, lp_type[['Type','L1']], on='Type', how='left')
results_type.sort_values(by='Supplier', inplace=True)

results_paygroup = pd.merge(results_type, lp_paygroup[['Paygroup','L2']], on='Paygroup', how='left')
results_paygroup.sort_values(by='Supplier', inplace=True)

type_from_paygroup = results_paygroup.copy()
type_from_paygroup['L1'] = results_paygroup.merge(lp_paygroup, on='Paygroup', how='left').apply(lambda r: r.L1_x if (r.L1_y is np.nan or r.L2_y == 'Vendor Level') else r.L1_y, axis=1)
type_from_paygroup.sort_values(by='Supplier', inplace=True)

paygroup_from_type = type_from_paygroup.copy()
paygroup_from_type['L2'] = type_from_paygroup.merge(lp_type, on='Type', how='left').apply(lambda r: r.L2_x if (r.L2_y is np.nan or r.L2_y == 'Vendor Level') else r.L2_y, axis=1)
paygroup_from_type.sort_values(by='Supplier', inplace=True)
final = paygroup_from_type.replace(np.nan,'Missing')


final['Unique']=final['Vendor Number'].astype(str) + final['Vendor Site Code'].astype(str)
final2 = final.copy()
final2 = pd.merge(final2, NonPO[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
print(final2)
```

Comment: Please include samples of your input data in the text of your question, not as an external link or image, to make a [mcve]

Comment: @G. Anderson Thank you. My problem is that when I re-wrote my code with the dfs in a form of a dictionary (that was my original intent), the issue didn't occur at all. It is only in this form (using Excel files) when the issue occurs. The files linked are just a sample (a few rows each). I would like to avoid linking external files if that's an issue, but I don't see a way around this. I hope it maks sense? Thank you.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you. I have edited my question and added full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `NonPO` as your data frame, but in fact this is the variable that contains that filename, which is a string. Here it's clear

```
NonPO_Suppliers = pd.read_excel(NonPO)
```

Just change `NonPO` to `NonPO_Suppliers` and you should be fine.

```
final2 = pd.merge(final2, NonPO_Suppliers[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I just assumed that the issue arose from the fact that I was concatenating strings numbers and just missed the obvious error. That was brilliant!

Comment: It happens all the time, don't worry!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
NonPO = r'//eu.ad.hertz.com/userdocs/irac920/Desktop/My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/Non-PO Suppliers.xlsx'
NonPO_Suppliers = pd.read_excel(NonPO) # this is the name of the DataFrame, not NonPO.
```

Consequently, you need to change your code to this:

```
final2 = pd.merge(final2, NonPO[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
final2 = pd.merge(final2, NonPO_Suppliers[['Unique','Category']], on='Unique', how='left')
```

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Thank you. It definitely resolved my issues. I can't accept two answers, unfortunately as I have accepted the previous one already! I'm sorry. But I really appreciate you looking into this and resolving so quickly!

Comment: No problem of course! Glad your issue got resolved. Any time you need some help just let me know and I'll try to help.